# Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub in requests module python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cookies

I want to check some usernames & password for logging in to GitHub.
I Inspected & got that the first input name of github login is "login" & second one is "password" & "Form" uses "POST" method. I have written this code but when I want to check this code, It tells me (`Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub`)

```
allData = {
    'login': x,
    'password': y
}

siteRequest = requests.post('https://github.com/login', data=allData)
print(siteRequest.content, end='\n\n')
```

How should I enable cookies ?
Note : I know github has API but some sites don't, So I want to increase my ability & knowledge about this method ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub's login page sets a cookie with a session ID on load, this session is used to keep you logged in.

To solve your problem simply create a requests session object, this will keep track of the cookies, then use the same session to post your login.

```
allData = {
    'login': x,
    'password': y
}

site_session = requests.Session()
_ = site_session.get('https://github.com/login')  # This is just to get the initial
                                                  # cookie in the session
siteRequest = site_session.post('https://github.com/login', data=allData)
print(siteRequest.content, end='\n\n')
```

Comment: Thanks My Friend, It is correct, But every Passwords & Usernames that I'm sure some of them are not matched, returns content of github login page ..., Truely I want to write something like Brute Force :), What is my problem ?